# How to get NiFi processor error into Flowfile attribute?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a PutGCSObject processor for which I want to capture the error into a flow file attribute.

[image]

As in the Picture, when there is an error for the Processor, it sends to failure with all the pre-existing attributes as-is.

[image]

I want the error message to be a part of the same flow file as an attribute. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: there is no normal way... however everything you see on the screen - you can get through api. activate devtools (f12) and see the api request that is used to render error message on the screen. you can call it with InvokeHttp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a way to get it.

Here is how i do it:

**1**: I route all ERROR connections to a main "monitoring process group"

**2**: Here is my "monitoring process group"

[image]

In `updateattribute` I capture **filename** as **initial_filename**

Then in my next step I query the bulletins

[image]

I then parse the output as individual attributes.

After I have the parsed bulleting output I use a RouteOnAttribute proc to drop all bulletins I don't need (some of them I have already used and notified on).

[image]

Once I only have my actual ERROR bulletin left, I use ExecuteStreamingCommand to run a python script using nipyapi module to get more info about the error, such as where it is in my flow, hierarchy, a description of the processor that failed, some proc stats and also I have metadata catalog about each proc/process group with their custodians and business use case.

This data is then posted to sumologic for logging and also I trigger a series of notifications (Slack + PagerDuty hook to create an incident lifecycle).

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Up_One . I achieved it with a similar way when @daggett pointed to use the API. I used the `/nifi-api/processors/{id}` GET request which gave me the bulletin info of that specific processor and used an Attribute to store the response via `Put Response Body In Attribute` parameter of InvokeHTTP. Later used the RouteonAttribute to search for the required error text using expression language

Comment: yes - that is also an approach, i did mine to cater for all my errors on the canvas so is more generic

Answer (score 1):

There's no universal way to append error messages as flowfile attributes. Also, we tend to strongly avoid anything like that because of the potential to bubble up error messages with sensitive data to users who might not be authorized to see those details.

Comment: i think the issue of error message access should not be decided on the level of platform because there are a lot of cases when it's required by flow. it's already available in executescript and in executestreamcommand. i believe there must be a switch to enable error message in attribute of flow file.

Comment: That would be impossible to force because the main design pattern in use for years has been try catch, send to failure on exception. You can't override that behavior from the framework level without the cooperation of all processor developers.

Comment: I think it's not so hard. 99% of processors using [getLogger().error(...)](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/9a3a659c441f7d4d61f7b526777f1a2def9198ac/nifi-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/AbstractControllerService.java#L97) to log the error occurred. exactly those errors going to be displayed in UI. so, why not to put the same error message to some standard (or customizable) attribute if feature turned on in nifi.properties?

Comment: As mentioned above, there are plenty of times where an error might have details that shouldn't be bubbled up. Adding that to the flow bulletin can be bad enough; adding them as attributes would preserve the details in the provenance data.

Comment: FWIW, I get the issue. I brought it up once myself, and the explanation from other committers was along those lines of it compounding data leakage.

Comment: That's why it should be manageable. some processors already has this feature. look at [invokehttp.java.exception.message](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/). sometimes we can take a decision where to flow based on error message. by following your logic the error messages should be turned off on the level of java language...

Comment: There are much better ways to do the error handling such as using attributes that have the http code and doing routeonattribute.